# Can't make NULLIF work using Window Functions of postgres 10

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use NULLIF to avoid division by zero error when using the *over* window function of postgres.

It throws "syntax error at or near "over"."

I'm using this query:

```
  SELECT 
    dlo.nombre_cadena, dpr.marca_producto,
    sum(rep.mes_33_uni) / NULLIF(sum(sum(rep.mes_33_uni)), 0) over (partition by dpr.marca_producto) AS porcentajep,
    FROM
    rpro_dim.reporte33_full rep
JOIN rpro_dim.dim_productos_retail dpr ON dpr.id_dim_prod_retail = rep.id_dim_prod_retail
JOIN rpro_dim.dim_locales dlo ON dlo.id_dim_local = rep.id_dim_localgroup by 
dlo.nombre_cadena, dpr.marca_producto
order by dlo.nombre_cadena, dpr.marca_producto
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
NULLIF(sum(sum(rep.mes_33_uni)), 0) over (partition by dpr.marca_producto) -- error!
```

you are trying to execute `nullif()` as a window function.

You should put the whole expression as an argument for `nullif()`:

```
NULLIF(sum(sum(rep.mes_33_uni)) over (partition by dpr.marca_producto), 0)
```